# Forwarding a function to std::thread via a lambda expression

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm working through the notes [here](https://github.com/peter-can-write/cpp-notes/blob/master/future-and-promise.md) to understand an example async function implementation.

Attempting to compile the below code

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <type_traits>


int f(int x) {
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t start_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(start);
    std::cout << "returning " << x << " at " << std::ctime(&start_time) << std::endl;
    return x;
}


template<typename Function, typename... Args>
auto async(Function&& function, Args&&... args) {

    std::promise<typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type> outer_promise;
    auto future = outer_promise.get_future();
    auto lambda = [function, promise = std::move(outer_promise)](Args&&... args) mutable {
        try {
            promise.set_value(function(args...));
        } catch (...) {
            promise.set_exception(std::current_exception());
        }
    };

    std::thread t0(std::move(lambda), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    t0.detach();
    return future;
}

int main() {

    auto result1 = async(f, 1); 
    auto result2 = async(f, 2); 

}
```

I get the following compiler errors, which I'm struggling to understand.

I'd like some guidance on why this `function` arg is not declared correctly according to the compiler.

```
In instantiation of 'async(Function&&, Args&& ...)::<lambda(Args&& ...)> mutable [with Function = int (&)(int); Args = {int}]':
22:61:   required from 'struct async(Function&&, Args&& ...) [with Function = int (&)(int); Args = {int}]::<lambda(int&&)>'
28:3:   required from 'auto async(Function&&, Args&& ...) [with Function = int (&)(int); Args = {int}]'
37:27:   required from here
22:88: error: variable 'function' has function type
22:88: error: variable 'function' has function type
 In instantiation of 'struct async(Function&&, Args&& ...) [with Function = int (&)(int); Args = {int}]::<lambda(int&&)>':
28:3:   required from 'auto async(Function&&, Args&& ...) [with Function = int (&)(int); Args = {int}]'
37:27:   required from here
22:18: error: field 'async(Function&&, Args&& ...) [with Function = int (&)(int); Args = {int}]::<lambda(int&&)>::<function capture>' invalidly declared function type
```

Comment: What compiler do you use? `g++ 11.2` doesn't seem to have any problem with this: [test on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31526640df41c981)

Comment: You're right. I upgraded my gcc. Confirmed working on 9.4..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get result type of `result_of` you have to access `type`:

```
std::promise< typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type > outer_promise;
```

Comment: lambda is inside `{}`. But this is obvious error, and these brackets should be removed.

Comment: Making these updates I'm still getting the same error.

`22:90: error: variable 'function' has function type`